# Html4 browsers does not support history.pushState and history.replaceState methods of History API from HTML5

Tags: ember.js, pushstate, history.js

I am working on an ember application (using ember-1.0.pre.js). And I'm trying to provide cross browser compatibility on IE8.

The issue is with url generate after every transition, it seems incorrect/falsy to user. Let say I hit the url like  `the_ domain_name/sell/new` which initially land me to on sell page of our application. and then i tries to transit a new state called "Purchase" which will land me on purchase page of our application.
 The new state transition generates a URL  `the_ domain_name/sell/new#/offers/purchase?&suid=1365149991779013736531657156165` in IE8 addressbar instead of `the domain_name/offers/purchase`.

**Note:** the_domain_name = `http://www.example.com`

The generated url includes two incorrect things,

1. The initial prefix "/sell/new#".
2. The parameter "?&_suid=1365149991779013736531657156165" in query string of url.

I tried to figure out the issue and found that HTML4 browsers does not supports pushState and replaceState methods from History API from HTML5. How can i provide the support on IE8 Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Use Modernizr to check for feature, and use a polyfill for non-supported browsers.  http://modernizr.com/docs/#polyfills

Answer (score 11):

I suggest `History.js` as polyfill for browsers not support History API:  https://github.com/browserstate/history.js

It is working in:

**HTML5 Browsers:**

- Firefox 4+
- Chrome 8+
- Opera 11.5
- Safari 5.0+
- Safari iOS 4.3+

**HTML4 Browsers:**

- IE 6, 7, 8, 9
- Firefox 3
- Opera 10, 11.0
- Safari 4
- Safari iOS 4.2, 4.1, 4.0, 3.2

Add [jquery.history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/blob/master/scripts/bundled/html4+html5/jquery.history.js) & Register a `history.js` location handler into you Ember App.

Here are the parts I modified from original `Ember.HistoryLocation` ( [Full code](http://pastebin.com/Gp4uMTQL) )

```
(function() {
  var get = Ember.get, set = Ember.set;
  var popstateFired = false;
  Ember.HistoryJsLocation = Ember.Object.extend({
    initState: function() {
      this.replaceState(this.formatURL(this.getURL()));
      set(this, 'history', window.History);
    },
    getState: function() {
      return get(this, 'history').getState().state;
    },
    pushState: function(path) {
      History.pushState({ path: path }, null, path);
    },
    replaceState: function(path) {
      History.replaceState({ path: path }, null, path);
    }
  });
  Ember.Location.registerImplementation('historyJs', Ember.HistoryJsLocation);
})();
```

Then use this polyfill in your App:

```
App.Router.reopen({
  location: 'historyJs'
});
```

Comment: this is awesome, would make a great addition to ember.js - perhaps not in core but for sure as a plugin.

Comment: Reminder: Change the second parameter of `pushState/replaceState` to `document.title` if you want to keep the same title or implement your own title handler.