# Ember.js - Prevent re-render when switching route

Tags: ember.js

Simplified demo: http://jsfiddle.net/indream/KskXx/
(this demo cannot simulate actual environment with my problem)

For the demo: Hover on photos will show you the caption.
When you clicked a photo, route changed to 'media' with `{{linkTo}}` helper & lightbox opened.
When clicked place outside lightbox, route changed back to 'feed' by `history API` & lightbox closed.

**My question**: Template **re-rendered** when switch back to 'feed'.
<strike>(You can check it by hover on photos as caption lost after that.)</strike>
I want to stop this as the app lagged during re-render if there're lots of photos.

***Using `{{linkTo}}` is the reason of problem, please refer to my answer***

I've read servel releated question like [Ember.js - currentViewBinding and stop re-rendering on every view transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908205/) and [Animating views before destruction in Emberjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15092632/).
But the methods provided seems not work for RC2, I've tried to modify `willDestroy` event, it works for not re-render but it throwed:
`Uncaught Error: Cannot perform operations on a Metamorph that is not in the DOM.`
`Uncaught Error: NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8`
when I switched to another route (i.e. empty `nowContent` for loading other content). And modify `destroyElement` isn't work at all.

Here's my code, any ideas to solve my problem?

```
App.MainView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName:'main',
  willDestroy: function() {
    if (App.get('destroyCurrentView')){
      this._super();
    }
  }
})
App.PageController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  lightboxClose:function(e){
    if(!e||e.target==e.currentTarget){
      $('#lightbox').hide();
      $('body').removeClass('noscroll');
      history.back();

      App.set('destroyCurrentView',false);
      setTimeout(function(){
        App.set('destroyCurrentView',true);
      }, 500);
    }
});
App.MediaRoute = App.mainRoute.extend({
  enter:function(){
    App.set('destroyCurrentView',false);
    this._super();
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure which template is re-rendering. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @ChristopherSwasey The `main` template re-rendered when switched back to `feed` route.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this by changing `{{linkTo}}` to `{{action}}` & editing the `onUpdateURL` handler of location API.

As `{{linkTo}}` must bubble up to Router while `{{action}}` not. With this approach, URL still changes for page refresh like Facebook but template will not re-render.

Old Template:

```
{{#linkTo media feed.id}}
<img src="{{unbound feed.images.low_resolution.url}}" />
{{/linkTo}}
```

New Template:

```
<img {{action transitionToMedia feed.id}} src="{{unbound feed.images.low_resolution.url}}" />
```

Location Handler:

```
Ember.HistoryJsLocation = Ember.Object.extend({
  onUpdateURL: function(callback) {
    ...
    Ember.$(window).bind('popstate.ember-location-'+guid, function(e) {
      if(window.suppressUpdateURL)return;
      ...
    });
  }
});

Ember.Location.registerImplementation('historyJs', Ember.HistoryJsLocation);
```

Router Event:

```
App.mainRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  events: {
    transitionToMedia: function (id) {
      window.suppressUpdateURL = true;
      History.pushState(null, null, '/m/'+id);
      App.pageController.lightbox(id);
    }
  }
});
```

Lightbox Controller:

```
Folo.PageController = Em.Controller.extend({
  lightboxClose: function(e){
    ...
    History.back();
    window.suppressUpdateURL = false;
  }
});
```

Note: Complete code for `HistoryJsLocation` please refer to [Html4 browsers does not support history.pushState and history.replaceState methods of History API from HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15835397/)